# Can't discover docker container on user defined network

Tags: linux, networking, docker, docker-network

Since i updated to Docker version 1.10 i'm not able to find other containers on the user defined network. I'm not able to ping the newly created container connected to the same network.

I've created a network called "my_net". Then I'm creating a container with the flag: "--net=my_net" and calling it: "first_container". Then When I start another container with the same flag for network mode, and start a ping to "first_container" I get the error message: "bad message". If I however ping the ip address that I can read from network inspect I'm able to ping.

## Versions:

- Docker version **1.10.0**, build 590d5108
- CentOS Linux release **7.2.1511** (Core)
- Kernel **3.10.0-327.4.5.el7.x86_64**

In the following sequence you can see what I'm doing.

```
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker network create --driver bridge my_net
8df716599f5160cf049014711c746a225c637a9dea7cb1a788ec7463c3273e4e
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
4b868a0b1e5c        none                null
0cfa087db0fc        host                host
8df716599f51        my_net              bridge
b7665552cf83        bridge              bridge
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker run -d --name first_container --net=my_net busybox top
750547995a2e515f51d93392d08f4e61d1841be452ad4e4139b5ba13148eee29
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker network inspect my_net
[
    {
        "Name": "my_net",
        "Id": "8df716599f5160cf049014711c746a225c637a9dea7cb1a788ec7463c3273e4e",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {
            "750547995a2e515f51d93392d08f4e61d1841be452ad4e4139b5ba13148eee29": {
                "Name": "first_container",
                "EndpointID": "a7fb91ac1b934370699a3f916b6f56c0f81d262a6c2610e9f9ec86cded199bef",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {}
    }
]
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker run --rm --net=my_net busybox cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.18.0.3      c2da8f1556e8
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker run --rm --net=my_net busybox ping -c1 first_container
ping: bad address 'first_container'
[my_user@my_machine ] $ docker run --rm --net=my_net busybox ping -c1 172.18.0.2
PING 172.18.0.2 (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.181 ms

--- 172.18.0.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.181/0.181/0.181 ms
[my_user@my_machine ] $
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: When I tried it again today, it worked. So I guess the case is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if restarting the Docker service the issue solves `sudo service docker restart`? Also, could you check if the `first_container` is running when you execute the `ping` command? I have been able to follow your steps and make a ping successfully. I have tested that using `Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108` and `Docker version 1.10.1, build 9e83765`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer.  I'm running "Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108" (on CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)). I've tried restarting the service several times.  the "first_container" is running and I'm able to ping it using it's ip (172.18.0.2). So this is just about name resolution.